# Track client TLS version from Self-Hosted WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl, networking, tls1.2

We need to track client TLS version for self-hosted WCF services with HTTPS binding in order to detect users with outdated version (TLS 1.0) to contact them with request to update.

.NET Framework version is 4.7.2
IIS hosting is not an option. Maybe there is some network tool similar to Wireshark to track this info on the server?

P.S.
My question is very similar to this one, but it is still not yet resolved:
[WCF service (self-hosted) over HTTPS - Get negotiated SSL/TLS protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875539/wcf-service-self-hosted-over-https-get-negotiated-ssl-tls-protocol-version)

Answer (score 1):

If you capture the connection creation in Wireshark, and examine the first packet from the client, then Wireshark will annotate the fields in the ClientHello struct for you, including the TLS version requested by the client.

Similarly, if you look at the first reply packet from the server, then Wireshark will annotate the fields in the ServerHello struct for you, including the TLS version settled on for the connection.

Here is the reference:[The First Few Milliseconds of an HTTPS Connection](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html)
and [How to test which version of TLS my .NET client is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276358/how-to-test-which-version-of-tls-my-net-client-is-using)